# Mockito cannot mock this class - Caused by: NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/ObjectInputFilter$FilterInfo

Tags: mockito, java-11, java-9

While executing JUnits with OpenJdk-11, Mockito-3.12.4 and powermock-2.0.9 getting below error. Also, I am using third party library (pcm.jar) which is compiled by Java 1.8.

Error is -

```
shouldReturnSecondaryDataServiceMapFromFList(com.xxxxx.SecondaryDataServiceMapTest)  Time elapsed: 0.301 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.portal.pcm.FList.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.
Java               : 11
JVM vendor name    : Red Hat, Inc.
JVM vendor version : 11.0.15+9-LTS
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 11.0.15+9-LTS
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Windows 10
OS version         : 10.0
You are seeing this disclaimer because Mockito is configured to create inlined mocks.
You can learn about inline mocks and their limitations under item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc.
Underlying exception : org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [class java.util.Hashtable, class com.portal.pcm.FList, interface java.io.Externalizable, class java.util.Dictionary]
```

```
      at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
      at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
      at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309)
      at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodList$ForLoadedMethods.<init>(MethodList.java:148)
      at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$ForLoadedType.getDeclaredMethods(TypeDescription.java:8655)
      at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.InstrumentedType$Factory$Default$1.represent(InstrumentedType.java:421)
      at net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy.redefine(ByteBuddy.java:782)
      at net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy.redefine(ByteBuddy.java:757)
      at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.transform(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:381)
      at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:246)
      at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
      at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:563)
      at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
      at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:167)
      at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:276)
      ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.ObjectInputFilter$FilterInfo
      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
      ... 65 more
```

sun.misc.* is deprecated. Which jar is referring this class? Is it mockito or pcm.jar?

What dependency I need to include or exclude for sun.misc.ObjectInputFilter?

Comment: What dependency I need to include or exclude for sun.misc.ObjectInputFilter? - Java?

Comment: @hovanessyan, these classes deprecated in Java 11, since I am using libraries which are build on Java 8 may need these classes. How to add externally.

Comment: "You are seeing this disclaimer because Mockito is configured to create inlined mocks.
You can learn about inline mocks and their limitations under item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc.". Have you read #39 of the JavaDoc?